# Show a 'new' badge on a docusaurus sidebar item

Tags: css, docusaurus

I'm using docusaurus for our product documentation.

Regarding the sidebar, I would like to add a 'new' badge after some sidebar items to indicate that the item documentation is new.

Something like that:
[new label on item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Wy9.png)

To do that, in `sidebar.js`, I tried to do this:

```json
{
          "type": "doc",
          "id": "mydocid",
          "label": 'mydoc subject',
          "className": "newText"
},
```

I tried to use .newText::after to add an image but it doesn't work. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a workaround. The advantages of this solution is that docusaurus generates a sidebar for you. Therefore, you do not need to maintain the sidebar.

In the `sidebar.js` file, you can keep it as autogenerated.

```js
const sidebars = {
  docs: [{type: 'autogenerated', dirName: '.'}],
};
```

Add the new badge (emoji) in the markdown title like so:

```
# Test
```

Sidebar result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks johann, excellent simple solution.